# Get data of every hour in date range

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get prices of every hour in a given date range, i am using pandas datareader.

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime as dt

ticker = 'BTC-USD'


start = dt.datetime(2014, 9, 22)
end = dt.datetime.today()
prices = web.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start, end)['Close']
returns = prices.pct_change()
last_price = prices[-1]
print(prices)
```

The above code gives prices for every day close, how can I change it so it gives prices for every hour close?

Answer (score 0):

Put you code inside loop for 24 hours and update start and end in every iteration.

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime as dt

ticker = 'BTC-USD'


start = dt.datetime(2014, 9, 22)
for i in range(24):
    end = start + dt.timedelta(hours=1)
    prices = web.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start, end)['Close']
    returns = prices.pct_change()
    last_price = prices[-1]
    print(prices)
    start=end
```